# Whenever I use cvMatchTemplate in openCV, I get a segmentation fault. Why?

Tags: opencv, template-matching

I'm trying to do a simple template match in openCV and at the line in my code where I call cvMatchTemplate, I get a segmentation fault.  I don't know if this is relevant, but i'm on a mac using x11 and i'm using opencv 2.0.0.

Here is relevant code:

IplImage* imgOriginal = cvLoadImage("reference.png", 0);
 IplImage* imgTemplate = cvLoadImage("template.png", 0);

IplImage* imgResult = cvCreateImage(cvSize(imgOriginal->width-imgTemplate->width+1, imgOriginal->height-imgTemplate->height+1), IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1);
    cvZero(imgResult);

cvMatchTemplate(imgOriginal, imgTemplate, imgResult, CV_TM_CCOEFF_NORMED);
...

I copied this code from a really good tutorial I found online and it seemed like things should work out, but I can't seem to get it. Also, the last parameter in cvMatchTemplate can vary based on how we want to compute the matching and I've tried them all and they call create a segementation fault.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?  Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing a real backtrace (try running with [gdb](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CBgQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Fmac%2Flibrary%2Fdocumentation%2FDarwin%2FReference%2FManPages%2Fman1%2Fgdb.1.html&ei=mZ5ATJjPDYbksQOu87mkDA&usg=AFQjCNGY1pjk6qvcv-70y-iIPJoU_rKRlw&sig2=O8i_04WIR-0b8MFu0QjFTg)), it's hard to tell. Check that `imgOriginal` and `imgTemplate` aren't null?